# Return image from DB and display with .NET API and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I wanna achieve a simple task, which is to retrieve the binary image, and display it in my html

public class Artwork

```
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid artworkID { get; set; }
    public string artworkName { get; set; }
    public string artworkMimeType { get; set; }
    public byte[] artworkMeta { get; set; }
    public string artworkBase64String { get; set; }
}
```

Gets the artwork from DB

```
public Artwork GetArtwork(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.Artworks.SingleOrDefault(a => a.artworkID == id);
    }
```

The API Controller

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var artwork = _repository.GetArtwork(id);
            if (artwork == null)
                return NotFound();
            else
                return Ok(artwork);
        }
```

I've also used this method and it returns the data I want, but I still don't know how to use it to achieve my goal.

```
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        try
        {
            var artwork = _repository.GetArtwork(id);

            if (artwork == null)
            {
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
            }
            else
            {
                // sendo file to client
                byte[] bytes = artwork.artworkMeta ;


                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = artwork.artworkName;
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
        }
    }
```

And here's my angular request

```
$scope.getCity = function (id) {
            $http.get('/api/artwork/' + $RouteParams.id).success(function (response) {
                $scope.artwork= response;
                //I've seen dudes using Blob here, but I'm not sure how that works
            });
        }
```

My problem is my angular request and my html, how do I display the artwork without doing this:

```
<img ng-src="data:{{artwork.artworkartworkMimeType}};base64,{{artwork.artworkBase64String}}" class="img-responsive" />
```

This displays the image, but I don't like how clumsy it looks, and I'm gonna be working with audio files as well, so I need a clean and understandable way. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, this can be done by using a blob.

First step is to set the content type to `application/octet-stream` in the api method

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = null;
    try
    {
        var artwork = _repository.GetArtwork(id);
        if (artwork == null)
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
        }
        else
        {
            // sendo file to client
            byte[] bytes = artwork.artworkMeta ;
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = artwork.artworkName;
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        } 

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
    }
}
```

Then add the client request where you create a blob from the response. An url is then created for the blob which will be the source for the img

```
$scope.fileURL = '';
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/artwork/' + $RouteParams.id,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
}).success(function (data, status, headers) {
    headers = headers();
    var contentType = headers['content-type'];
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
    //Create a url to the blob 
    $scope.fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

}).error(function (message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Then bind url to the ngSrc

```
<img ng-src="{{fileURL}}" class="img-responsive" />
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and cleaned my code a lot. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Great! Np, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could store image in binary format without encoding it to base64. Then it would be simpler to retrive image from DB.
In your asp controller:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public FileResult GetPhoto(int id) {

      return File(_repository.GetArtwork(id).artworkMeta, "image/jpg");

  }
```

And in angular view:

```
  <img ng-src="/Home/GetPhoto/2" />
```